# Unable to upload to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

```
    sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
 !
 !     Could not detect rake tasks
 !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
 !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
 !     rake aborted!
 !     Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'geocoder'.
 !     /tmp/build_9b4051bc141f7a675f608a4f23fe3255/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require'
 !     /tmp/build_9b4051bc141f7a675f608a4f23fe3255/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
 !     /tmp/build_9b4051bc141f7a675f608a4f23fe3255/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
 !     /tmp/build_9b4051bc141f7a675f608a4f23fe3255/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
 !     /tmp/build_9b4051bc141f7a675f608a4f23fe3255/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
 !     /tmp/build_9b4051bc141f7a675f608a4f23fe3255/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
 !     /tmp/build_9b4051bc141f7a675f608a4f23fe3255/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
 !     /tmp/build_9b4051bc141f7a675f608a4f23fe3255/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
 !     /tmp/build_9b4051bc141f7a675f608a4f23fe3255/Rakefile:4:in `require'
 !     /tmp/build_9b4051bc141f7a675f608a4f23fe3255/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
 !     /tmp/build_9b4051bc141f7a675f608a4f23fe3255/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
 !     /tmp/build_9b4051bc141f7a675f608a4f23fe3255/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
 !     /tmp/build_9b4051bc141f7a675f608a4f23fe3255/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
 !     /tmp/build_9b4051bc141f7a675f608a4f23fe3255/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
 !     /tmp/build_9b4051bc141f7a675f608a4f23fe3255/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
 !     /tmp/build_9b4051bc141f7a675f608a4f23fe3255/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
 !     /tmp/build_9b4051bc141f7a675f608a4f23fe3255/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
 !     /tmp/build_9b4051bc141f7a675f608a4f23fe3255/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
 !     /tmp/build_9b4051bc141f7a675f608a4f23fe3255/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
 !     /tmp/build_9b4051bc141f7a675f608a4f23fe3255/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
 !     vendor/bundle/bin/rake:16:in `load'
 !     vendor/bundle/bin/rake:16:in `<main>'
 !
/app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/helpers/rake_runner.rb:102:in `load_rake_tasks!': Could not detect rake tasks (LanguagePack::Helpers::RakeRunner::CannotLoadRakefileError)
ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
and using the production group of your Gemfile.
rake aborted!
Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'geocoder'.
/tmp/build_9b4051bc141f7a675f608a4f23fe3255/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require'
/tmp/build_9b4051bc141f7a675f608a4f23fe3255/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/tmp/build_9b4051bc141f7a675f608a4f23fe3255/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
/tmp/build_9b4051bc141f7a675f608a4f23fe3255/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
/tmp/build_9b4051bc141f7a675f608a4f23fe3255/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
/tmp/build_9b4051bc141f7a675f608a4f23fe3255/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
/tmp/build_9b4051bc141f7a675f608a4f23fe3255/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
/tmp/build_9b4051bc141f7a675f608a4f23fe3255/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/tmp/build_9b4051bc141f7a675f608a4f23fe3255/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/tmp/build_9b4051bc141f7a675f608a4f23fe3255/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/tmp/build_9b4051bc141f7a675f608a4f23fe3255/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/tmp/build_9b4051bc141f7a675f608a4f23fe3255/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/tmp/build_9b4051bc141f7a675f608a4f23fe3255/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/tmp/build_9b4051bc141f7a675f608a4f23fe3255/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/tmp/build_9b4051bc141f7a675f608a4f23fe3255/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/tmp/build_9b4051bc141f7a675f608a4f23fe3255/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/tmp/build_9b4051bc141f7a675f608a4f23fe3255/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/tmp/build_9b4051bc141f7a675f608a4f23fe3255/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/tmp/build_9b4051bc141f7a675f608a4f23fe3255/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/tmp/build_9b4051bc141f7a675f608a4f23fe3255/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
vendor/bundle/bin/rake:16:in `load'
vendor/bundle/bin/rake:16:in `<main>'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:746:in `rake'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in run_assets_precompile_rake_task'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:131:in `log'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:71:in `block in run_assets_precompile_rake_task'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:70:in `run_assets_precompile_rake_task'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:104:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:767:in `allow_git'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:98:in `block in compile'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:88:in `compile'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:49:in `block in compile'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:47:in `compile'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:38:in `block in compile'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:37:in `compile'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:41:in `block in compile'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:40:in `compile'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/bin/compile:16:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:131:in `log'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/bin/compile:15:in `block in <main>'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in `block in trace'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in `trace'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/bin/compile:11:in `<main>'
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

As per the above, I'm not able to upload to Heroku.. I've been able to run bundle exec rake -P against the application... I'm thinking perhaps the geocoded gem is the issue? I've removed it from my gem file however it is still installing it...

I'm not sure how to run bundle exec rake -P against my production environment... any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: you need to push Gem lock file on heroku and test it

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I've deleted my lock file bundle install and then tried to push update... nothing, I have no idea... it was working fine I changed some HTML code and it's started doing this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails comes bundled with a rake test to compile to asset manifests and other files in pipeline. you need to call this on server during deployment to create compiled version of your assets directly on server run below command.

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production bin/rake assets:precompile

$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle rake assets:precompile
```

This will solve your problem. To find more about it please follow [this.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)